# ClassCastException during QuarkusTest with OptaPlanner and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, quarkus, optaplanner, timefold

I'm using OptaPlanner `9.37.0.Final` with quarkus `3.1.3.Final` and Kotlin `1.8.21` to solve a VRP.

When I run `quarkusDev`, my current setup runs just fine, but when I run a `@QuarkusTest`, I get the following `ClassCastException`, hinting that something with class loading might be broken.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.domain.LoadJob$OptaPlanner$MemberAccessor$Field$arrivalTime cannot be cast to class org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.MemberAccessor (com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.domain.LoadJob$OptaPlanner$MemberAccessor$Field$arrivalTime is in unnamed module of loader 'OptaPlanner Gizmo SolutionCloner ClassLoader' @611d16c9; org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.MemberAccessor is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @319988b0)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberAccessorImplementor.createInstance(GizmoMemberAccessorImplementor.java:118)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberAccessorImplementor.createAccessorFor(GizmoMemberAccessorImplementor.java:112)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberAccessorFactory.buildGizmoMemberAccessor(GizmoMemberAccessorFactory.java:40)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.MemberAccessorFactory.buildMemberAccessor(MemberAccessorFactory.java:38)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.MemberAccessorFactory.lambda$buildAndCacheMemberAccessor$0(MemberAccessorFactory.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.MemberAccessorFactory.buildAndCacheMemberAccessor(MemberAccessorFactory.java:124)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.entity.descriptor.EntityDescriptor.processPlanningVariableAnnotation(EntityDescriptor.java:239)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.entity.descriptor.EntityDescriptor.processAnnotations(EntityDescriptor.java:154)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolutionDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolutionDescriptor(DefaultSolverFactory.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.<init>(DefaultSolverFactory.java:69)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.create(SolverFactory.java:106)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider.solverFactory(DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider.java:46)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_3b1fa4ff0a3de7781ba3e1239701086bba97ef14_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_3b1fa4ff0a3de7781ba3e1239701086bba97ef14_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_3b1fa4ff0a3de7781ba3e1239701086bba97ef14_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_3b1fa4ff0a3de7781ba3e1239701086bba97ef14_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.quarkus.bean.DefaultOptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.rest.SolverResource_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.rest.SolverResource_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.rest.SolverResource_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:113)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:37)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
    at com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.rest.SolverResource_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.cargonexx.vehiclerouting.rest.SolverResource_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:499)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:479)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:512)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$2.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:287)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$2.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:284)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainerImpl$1.create(BeanContainerImpl.java:46)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.ArcBeanFactory.createInstance(ArcBeanFactory.java:27)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InstanceHandler.handle(InstanceHandler.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have a `PlanningEntity` along the lines of:

```
@PlanningEntity
class LoadJob {
    @PlanningId lateinit var id: String

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tour") //
    var vehicle: Vehicle? = null

    @PreviousElementShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tour") //
    var previousLoadJob: LoadJob? = null

    @NextElementShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tour") //
    var nextLoadJob: LoadJob? = null

    @JvmField
    @ShadowVariable(
        variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdateListener::class,
        sourceVariableName = "vehicle"
    )
    @ShadowVariable(
        variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdateListener::class,
        sourceVariableName = "previousLoadJob"
    )
    var arrivalTime: LocalDateTime? = null
}
```

which is used in the `PlanningListVariable` in the `Vehicle` class:

```
@PlanningEntity
class Vehicle {
    @PlanningId lateinit var planningId: String

    @PlanningListVariable lateinit var tour: MutableList<LoadJob>
}
```

Both are part of the `PlanningSolution`

```
@PlanningSolution
class TourPlan {
    lateinit var id: String

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty //
    lateinit var vehicles: List<Vehicle>

    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty //
    lateinit var loadJobs: List<LoadJob>

    @PlanningScore //
    var score: HardMediumSoftLongScore? = null

    @ConstraintConfigurationProvider
    var constraintConfiguration: TourPlanConstraintConfiguration = TourPlanConstraintConfiguration()

    constructor() // required for optaplanner
}
```

Has anybody else run into an issue like that? Are there any known workarounds or fixes for this issue?

I have been working for almost a month with this setup now, but in the long run it might not be feasible to just don't run any `QuarkusTest`s as they are broken with the current setup.

**Notes**

- When using `REFLECTION` instead of `GIZMO` for optaplanner domain access, I don't have this issue. However, since reflection is slower, as the optaplanner documentation also mentions, I'd like to be able to use `GIZMO` for the performance gain and not have to use diverging configurations for tests and regular builds
- I'm aware of the fact that quarkus loads classes differently during tests. Unfortunately, I haven't had the time yet to look into quarkus class loading in depth (or at least further than the documentation goes)
- I have stumbled upon https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34099 and https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/34681 which may be related to the root cause of this exception, but that's more a guess than anything I could say for sure.
- I haven't tried if the problem also exists with timefold instead of optaplanner yet, but I'd be willing to invest the time and try to extract a reproducer with timefold in case that's of interest to the timefold team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this [issue was fixed](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/117) in Timefold 1.0.0. (The issue description helpfully also contains a workaround, which you already found yourself.) Please check that version and, if your case is still not fixed, kindly [file an issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/), ideally with a reproducer.

Whether OptaPlanner will fix this issue and when, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, timefold 1.0.0 indeed fixes that issue. Unfortunately, since multithreaded incremental solving gives us a significant performance boost and the pricing model for timefold enterprise does not seem to be decided yet, we are hesitant to migrate... 

Might be worth opening a small PR on optaplanner ourselves - although we don't know if that would get merged anytime soon, since Geoffrey and you moved to timefold.

So I suppose we will just have to weigh our options :)

Comment: The rules of StackOverflow do not allow solicitation, so I will not tell you to contact Timefold to see what the options would be. ;-)

Comment: I think our team lead did have that on his tasklist regardless ;)